# My SQL Dynamic query execute and get ouput into a variable in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql, dynamic-queries

I generate a dynamic query in My sql Stored procedure. I wanna get the result of this query into a out parameter. How to do this ?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 'searchInvoice'
(
  OUT numOfRecords INT
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE query1 TEXT; 
  DECLARE query2 TEXT; 

 SET query1 = 'SELECT COUNT(*) bla bla bla.....'; 
 // Query1 to select the count of matching tuples..

 SET query2 = 'SELECT * from bla bla bla....';
 // Query2 to select original records...

 // later part of this both queries generate dynamically according to some IN parameters..

 // now I wanna assign the output of the query1 into numOfRecords 
 // and I wanna execute the query2 as well.. like this

    SET @Sql = query2;        
    PREPARE STMT FROM @Sql; 
    EXECUTE STMT; 
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;

 // output of the query2 can be read in PHP

END
```

How to get the output of the query1 into OUT parameter(`numOfRecords` ) ??

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Have a look at this example -

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
  column1 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  column2 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  column3 VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES 
  ('1', 'value1', 'value2'),
  ('2', 'value3', 'value4');

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure1(IN Param1 VARCHAR(255), OUT Param2 VARCHAR(255), OUT Param3 VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
  SET @c2 = '';
  SET @c3 = '';
  SET @query = 'SELECT column2, column3 INTO @c2, @c3 FROM table1 WHERE column1 = ?';
  PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
  SET @c1 = Param1;
  EXECUTE stmt USING @c1;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  SET Param2 = @c2;
  SET Param3 = @c3;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

-- Call procedure and use variables
SET @Param1 = 2;
SET @Param2 = '';
SET @Param3 = '';
CALL procedure1(@Param1, @Param2, @Param3);
SELECT @Param2, @Param3;
+---------+---------+
| @Param2 | @Param3 |
+---------+---------+
| value3  | value4  |
+---------+---------+
```

Comment: @Devart what if getting multiple records, how to store in temp table?

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(*) into @numOfRecords from ....
```

You have do declare the variable within stored procedure

I hope I've understood your question.