# SQL - Select tables where row number is XX

Tags: mysql, sql

Been searching on Google for a while now without finding the answer to my problem. I have like 10 tables where 5 of them contains 150 rows. I want to add 15 rows to these 5 tables, is there any simple solution for this? I know it's easy to add the rows manually but I want to know anyway. What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
INSERT INTO all_tables VALUES (col1, col2, col3) WHERE row_number() = '150'
```

Is it possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using Oracle, SQL Server or something else?

Comment: Could you explain your problem in another way. It's unclear... Do you want to replicate the 150th row or add values where rows equal a certain value? Also what flavor of SQL?

Comment: You meean adding additional columns or inserting values into those columns?

Comment: I want to add 15 extra rows to all tables containing 150 rows. I'm using phpmyadmin.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin indicates MySQL. Tags updated accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

You can only target updates to one table at a time, which must always be specified by name. Also, you cannot specify a WHERE clause on an INSERT. Your best bet is probably to write one INSERT and copy and paste for the rest.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. Loop through a list of the relevant table names.
2. Run a dynamic query like `select count(*) into @c1 from SpecifiedTable` against the relevant table, returning the count into a declared variable.
3. If the returned value is 150, run another dynamic query to insert the relevant values into the specified table.

You can find out more about dynamic queries and returning values from them in MySQL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591338/my-sql-dynamic-query-execute-and-get-ouput-into-a-variable-in-stored-procedure). If this is a once-off, you will probably find it easier to do it manually.