# MySQL - How to get field value from dynamic query?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I wanna know how to get field value from dynamic query. I do it on stored-procedure in MySQL. I've the following code:

```
...
DECLARE l_query VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE l_table VARCHAR(50);

SET l_table = 'tb_user';
SET @l_query = concat('SELECT count(1) FROM ', l_table);
-- #Note that l_table will not always for tb_user,
-- it can be changed with other table name.

PREPARE l_sql FROM @l_query;
EXECUTE l_sql;
...
```

The question is, how to get value for count result (`count(1)`) ..? 
 I need this value, because **it will be used on the next process at the same stored procedure**.

Many thanks before.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591338/my-sql-dynamic-query-execute-and-get-ouput-into-a-variable-in-stored-procedure/5591433#5591433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short: Use `SELECT INTO` to select the value into variable.

In your case:

```
...
DECLARE l_query VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE l_table VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE cnt INTEGER;

SET l_table = 'tb_user';
SET @l_query = concat('SELECT count(1) INTO @cnt FROM ', l_table);
-- #Note that l_table will not always for tb_user,
-- it can be changed with other table name.

PREPARE l_sql FROM @l_query;
EXECUTE l_sql;
-- Use cnt variable here
...
```

Comment: owh great, so I can get the value from `@cnt`. Thank you so much.