# How to pass a Dynamic column name to a function parameter in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-python

Okay, I'm only looking for a work around now. Could some one guide me?

**EDIT:**
Okay, So apparantly there's no way to get a function to call a dynamic procedure in MySql.
But I really need to do this select statement dynamically!

```
SELECT Location FROM DemoTable WHERE No_of_Hospitals > AvgCity(No_of_Hospitals)
```

Or find a better way to deal with this problem.
The parameters in the AvgCity() will be dynamic all the time. That's kind of compulsory. The parameter passing will be the name of a column from the DemoTable.
I need an efficient way to handle the Rules from the Rule Table and the DemoTable as I've stated below. 
Its been 3 days now that i've been stuck on this.
**HELP!! :s**

For reference, here's the old problem i had. And the flow of everything that i've got done so far-

**Old Problem:**
Could some one help me out with a good way to go about this?
I'm pretty new to MySql and I can't seem to find a simple answer for this anywhere.
I have two tables that I'm working with. The first table contains a lot of columns filled with Integer values such as:

```
 No_of_Hotels  No_of_Hospitals
```

The second table is a Rule Table which contains a rule name followed by the actual rule.
Eg:

`ID    RuleName    Rule
  1    Example     No_of_Hospitals > AvgCity(No_of_Hospitals)`

The function that I have right now is:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION AvgCity(columnName text) RETURNS float(10)  
 DETERMINISTIC  
 BEGIN  
 DECLARE columnAvg float;  
 SELECT AVG(columnName)   
 INTO columnAvg 
 FROM DemoTable;
 RETURN (columnAvg);  
 END
```

But every time I pass a value to the function parameter - which is the name of one of the columns that I want the average for, I get a `0` in return.
I figured that this is happening because the parameter being passed into the `AVG()` Function is being passed as a string and not a column name.
So that's `AVG("No_of_Hospitals")` instead of `AVG(No_of_Hospitals)` which also returns `0`.
How do I fix this and get a result?

I'll be executing the whole thing after the result with:

```
SELECT @Q:= CONCAT('SELECT Location FROM DemoTable WHERE ', Rules.Rule) FROM
Rules     WHERE ID=1;
PREPARE stq FROM @Q;
EXECUTE stq;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stq;
```

It all goes in a SELECT statement so, I do need the `AvgCity()` to be a Function and NOT a Procedure.

**UPDATE 1:**
So I decided to put a procedure inside the function.
What i have now is this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION AvgCity(colName text) RETURNS float(10)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE colAvg float;
CALL AvgCityProcedure(colName,colAvg);
RETURN (colAvg);
END
```

And this Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AvgCityProcedure(
IN colName VARCHAR(100),
OUT colAvg FLOAT)
BEGIN
SET @c1 = 0.0;
SET @M:= colName;
SET @QUERY:= CONCAT('SELECT AVG(',@M,') INTO @C1 FROM DemoTable');
PREPARE stmt FROM @QUERY;
EXECUTE stmt; 
SET colAvg:=@C1;
SELECT colAvg;
END
```

**UPDATE 2:** ***I got the procedure working!***
Followed this really nice example:
[My SQL Dynamic query execute and get ouput into a variable in stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591338/my-sql-dynamic-query-execute-and-get-ouput-into-a-variable-in-stored-procedure)
<s>But i can't seem to manage to insert any value inside `colAvg`.
I tried a lot of combinations with the `@QUERY`, but i can't find the right one.
I keep ending up with `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1`</s>

But if i remove the `INTO colAvg` part and just do 
`SELECT @QUERY:= CONCAT('SELECT AVG(',@M,') FROM DemoTable');`
It totally prints the answer to screen. I need to return that to `colAvg`.
What am i doing wrong? 
Alright! I got the Procedure working properly!
I got another problem now.
I get an error while returning values from my function to the procedure.
It says dynamic sql not allowed inside the function.
But i used the dynamic sql inside my procedure :S
Whats happening here?!
What I need it to look like in the end is:
`SELECT Location FROM DemoTable WHERE No_of_Hospitals > AvgCity(No_of_Hospitals)`

Could someone please set up a small bounty on this? I haven't got a single answer in more than a week now. :(

Comment: Replace your function with a procedure?

Comment: But I cant use a procedure in a select statement :s

Answer (score 0):

I would simply put the whole query in a string (with concat, include the table name) and execute.