# Joining a table name based on joined field

Tags: mysql

I have a `logs` table where I store all kinds of log information. This table contains `foreign_table_name` and `foreign_table_id` columns.

When pulling in the logs, to verify that the foreign records still exists, I want to run a "variable" join statement, e.g. like this:

```
    SELECT * 
      FROM `logs`
INNER JOIN `[logs.foreign_table_name]` ON 
           `[logs.foreign_table_name].id` = `logs.foreign_table_id`
```

How can I dynamically "generate" these table names?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My SQL Dynamic query execute and get ouput into a variable in stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591338/my-sql-dynamic-query-execute-and-get-ouput-into-a-variable-in-stored-procedure)

Comment: And you dont need a `JOIN` a Dynamic `SELECT` should work

Comment: This query is just an example to illustrate what I'm after. I do need a `JOIN` as there is more data required (the query is fairly extensive). Also I'm not talking about `stored procedures`..

Comment: You need a dynamic query anyway. And if you want a more specific answer give  more details.  Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)